# How to check file integrity in read-write file system on linux

Tags: linux

I have no idea how to check the integrity of file on Linux read-write file system.

I tried with fs-verity but that one used for read only file system.
How to check file integrity on linux read-write file system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **You probably cannot**, and you should define what is "file integrity". Disks have (hardware, perhaps temporary) errors, some of them being transient. File system code (inside the Linux kernel) could have residual bugs. Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's%20theorem)

Comment: File integrity check nothing but we need to check the file data whether modified or not with use of checksum, md5, sha256sum and etc. before reading the file.

In read-write case, every time need to update the checksum value after write data on file system and then check the checkum value during read the file

Comment: Why do you need that? For what application? Is using redundancy on different Linux servers (e.g. NFS) not enough? What happens if another process is writing the file when you are checking or hashing it? On Linux systems, several processes (or pthreads) can access and even write the same file simultaneously